# Format Months in Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In the rails console I can put in:

```
3.months => 3 months
1.months => 1 month
```

I would like to have this output in my views as well, I tried:

```
<%= @plan_months.months %>
```

And It gives this output:

```
 31104000
```

`plan_months` => 12 it's a `Fixum`

**How can I get this output: `12 months`**

thanks

Comment: Not sure what are you asking, you want to print `3.months` like `3.months` in the view?? and not `31104000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works. Try using [pluralize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize)

view:

```
#{pluralize(@plan_months, "month")}
```

by the way, if you want to test it in the console, you should type:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
pluralize(@plan_months, "month")
```